# Cannot resolve methods requestLocationUpdates using a Pubnub tutorial

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-api, pubnub

Okay, this question has been asked and I have tried all of the solutions provided but none of them seem to work,

I am using a Pubnub tutorial which displays my location in real time on an Android app, I have encountered a few errors that I cannot resolve one mainly been 
"Cannot resolve methods requestLocationUpdates"

I have seen in previous posts to add, import android.location.LocationListener; to the imports but it doesnt change anything.

if anybody has any solution to this it would be great, also my other errors if you know.

Main Activity:

```
package nixerpubcom.nixerpub;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.pubnub.api.PubnubError;

import android.location.LocationListener;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

//Create Google API Client
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
//Create pubnub variable
private Pubnub mPubnub;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Start The Google Client
    this.buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    //Retrieve pubnub keys
    mPubnub = new Pubnub ("pub-c-fe4ed754-2b9d-4563-abb6-63c3f048f9ad","sub-c-82de7130-eacb-11e5-8346-0619f8945a4f");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

//Google Api build Method
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Implement the Connection Callback
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = createLocationRequest();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Connection to Google API Suspended ");

}

private LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    return mLocationRequest;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    broadcastLocation(location);
}


private void broadcastLocation(Location location) {
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
    try {
        message.put("lat", location.getLatitude());
        message.put("lng", location.getLongitude());
        message.put("alt", location.getAltitude());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    mPubnub.publish("A Channel Name", message, publishCallback);
}

KeyEvent.Callback publishCallback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
        Log.d("PUBNUB", response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
        Log.e("PUBNUB", error.toString());
    }
};

}
```

[This is the error I get for the Cannot resolve methods requestLocationUpdates, my other errors are also in there which is a TAG error and a pubnub error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcCMZ.jpg)

I am new to this so I apologise if the question is no formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the requestLocationUpdates method:

   ```
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
   ```

   It is expecting that the class that is calling (MainActivity) implements *com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener*, so you need to implement it, or change it with an anonymous class:

   ```
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
               mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                       // Here you have the updated location
                   }
               });
   }
   ```
2. The string TAG is not defined in this class, so create a field like this on your class:

   ```
   private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
   ```

   Tip: type "logt" + enter in Android Studio to generate this line.
3. The callback you want in

   ```
   KeyEvent.Callback publishCallback = new Callback() {...}
   ```

   is not from KeyEvent, but from *com.pubnub.api.Callback*

   ```
   com.pubnub.api.Callback publishCallback = new Callback() {...}
   ```

Please make sure your imports are right and that you asked for location in the manifest:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

or

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```